# Symfony3 Profiler Storage

Tags: redis, profiler, symfony

in the Docs

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/profiler/storage.html

you still can find Information about Profiler Storage.
I just checked the code and could not find any clues how to set a custom storage.
I also find no Documentation stating this except some @legacy notes in the Original Source at 2.8.

Is there a Reason why this was removed?
I was using redis to store this data with a lifetime of eta 1hour.
Now I need to run a manual cleanup to whipe all files in that directory.
If anybody has some clues or hints on helping me with this issue are appreceated ^^

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Tip of Matteo I was able to solve this quite flexible.
The Team of Symfony removed this, because it was hard coded into the Profiler Subsystem.
Instead of fixing this by adding a class parameter I had to solve it. :)

Ok, here is the code, If somebody needs this to.

First of all we need the Original Classes from Symfony 2.7 (at least I reused them as I only need the Redis Option ( I use it, because I can Compress the data using igbinary)

Next you need to implement a Compiler Pass.

```
        namespace AcmeBunlde\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass;

        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

        class ProfilerCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
        {

            /**
             * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
             *
             * @param ContainerBuilder $container
             */
            public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
            {
                $definition = $container->getDefinition('profiler');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.defaultEnabled%');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.class%');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.dsn%');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.username%');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.password%');
                $definition->addArgument('%acmebundle.profiler.ttl%');
                $definition->setClass('acmebundle\Profiler\Profiler');
            }
        }
```

This needs to be loaded inside the Bundle Loader:

```
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        ...
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ProfilerCompilerPass());
    }
```

After this we need to add the Configuration for the New Profiler Storage in the DependencyInjection Folder.

```
    namespace AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ArrayNodeDefinition;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

    /**
     * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
     *
     * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
     * @author Chris
     */
    class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
        {
            $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
            $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('library');

            $rootNode
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('profiler')
                        ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                        ->children()
                            ->booleanNode('defaultStorage')
                                ->defaultTrue()
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('class')
                                ->defaultValue('')
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('dsn')
                                ->defaultValue('')
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('username')
                                ->defaultValue('')
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('password')
                                ->defaultValue('')
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('ttl')
                                ->defaultValue('3600')
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end();
            return $treeBuilder();
        }
    }
```

Now set the Default Values in The Dependency Injection Bundle Loader

```
    <?php

    namespace AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;

    /**
     * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
     *
     * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
     * @author Chris 
     */
    class AcmeExtension extends Extension
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
        {

            $configuration = new Configuration();
            $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
            ...
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.defaultEnabled',$config['profiler']['defaultStorage']);
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.class',$config['profiler']['class']);
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.dsn',$config['profiler']['dsn']);
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.username',$config['profiler']['username']);
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.password',$config['profiler']['password']);
            $container->setParameter('acmebundle.profiler.ttl',$config['profiler']['ttl']);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

As Last Step you need to build a basic container for adding the new Profiler Handler.
I have choosen to implement it not to complex:

```
    <?php

        namespace AcmeBundle\Profiler;
        use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
        use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler as ProfilerSrc;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\ProfilerStorageInterface;

        /**
         * Profiler.
         */
        class Profiler extends ProfilerSrc
        {
            public function __construct(ProfilerStorageInterface $storage, LoggerInterface $logger, $defaultEnabled=true,$class=null,$dsn=null,$username=null,$password=null,$ttl=3600)
            {
                if($defaultEnabled!==true)
                {
                    $storage = new $class($dsn,$username,$password,$ttl);
                }
                parent::__construct($storage , $logger);
            }
        }
```

I have also added a Library to define the Constructor of the Storage Interface.

```
    <?php

        namespace AcmeBundle\Profiler;

        use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\ProfilerStorageInterface as ProfilerStorageSource;

        interface ProfilerStorageInterface extends ProfilerStorageSource
        {
            /**
             * ProfilerStorageInterface constructor.
             *
             * @param $dsn
             * @param $username
             * @param $password
             * @param $ttl
             */
            public function __construct($dsn,$username,$password,$ttl);
        }
```

All you need to do now is to define some Options in your config_dev.yml file.

```
acmebundle:
    profiler:
        defaultEnabled: false
        class:CLASSNAME INCLUDING NAMESPACE
        dsn: redis://localhost/1
        username: 
        password
        ttl: 3600
```

with defaultEnabled = true you can reenable to Original Handler.
the rest is, I believe self explaining.
username + password is from the original feature set.
(ttl == lifetime)

I hope this helps somebody else as well :)

Comment: We created a [ProfilerStorageBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sitetheory/profiler-storage-bundle) to maintain this feature set in future implementations of Symfony.  Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is marked as deprecated since 2.8 with the suppression in the 3.0. I can't find any motivation about in the [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16018). The doc is not yet updated as you mention.

The only suggestion is about a comment in [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3806):

> If you want to use your own implementation of a profiler storage,
>   then just override the profile.storage service.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks this helps me quite a bit.